# SQL error-how to retreive record with letter AND number

Tags: sql, sql-server

hello just starting off but am wondering if anyone has had this issue come up. i have a table with person IDs (mix of letter and numbers- a person ID is A123456)

This is the code I have
`Select * from personID where ID like '%___456'` <--this provides all records that end in 456

however, when i try it this way it gives blanks
`Select * from personID where ID like 'A%______'` <-- i want to retrieve all records that begin w 'A'

Updated: I have updated it to reflect the % and not & my mistake

Comment: `&` isn't a wildcard in T-SQL; `%` is. A quick read of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will tell you where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of different ways to accomplish this.

```
        where ID like '%456'
        OR 
        where right(ID,3) = '456'


       where ID like 'A%'
       OR 
       LEFT(ID,1) = 'A'


       where like 'A%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS --uppercase 
       where like 'a%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS --lowercase
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want ids that end in 456 the correct pattern is:

```
where ID like '%456'
```

I don't know where `&` comes from.  It is not a wildcard for characters in SQL or regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the personID starts with **A** or **a** then :

```
Select * from personID where ID like 'A%'
```

If you want all the personID only starts with **A** then :

```
 Select * from personID where ID like 'A%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```